# object detection loss function YOLO

Tags: loss-functions, object-detection, yolo

as we know , in detection we have 2 loss : one is localization loss other is classification loss , in the formulation the 1th , 2th term related to localization loss and 3th term is related to classification loss ,well , what is other terms? and why square root of w,h ?

[image: loss function]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1st term => Will penalize localization of center (x,y)

2nd term  =>  Will penalize height & width predictions (w,h). Square root is used to penalize smaller bounding boxes more compared to larger bounding boxes.

3rd term => If object is present, increase the confidence to IOU

4th term => If object is not present, decrease the confidence to 0

5th term  => Simple Object classification loss